# Is it possible to embed Model driven app to Power BI Dashboard similar to Canvas App?

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

Is it possible to embed Model driven app to Power BI Dashboard similar to Canvas App ?

Allow Power BI to embed model driven app

Is that limitation of Microsoft or any article from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

From the doc

"Using the Power Apps visual, you can pass context-aware data to a **canvas** app, which updates in real time as you make changes to your report"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-powerapp

Answer (score 0):

If you see, model driven power app is just an another website. So you can embed using [HTML5 PowerBI visual (Iframe)](https://whatthefact.bi/power-bi/data-visualization/display-website-within-power-bi-dynamically/) or [Web content tile](https://medium.com/@4ndres.gaviria/how-to-embed-a-website-into-a-powerbi-dashboard-206e33de9cf9).